# how do I manually add my USB stick that has OpenSUSE into the UEFI boot menu?

Tags: grub2, opensuse

So I installed OpenSUSE to a USB drive.

My problem is that if I pull it out, I cannot boot into it anymore. I tried adding a boot selection manually but it's not working. In this instance, I selected "boot/bootx64.efi".

Any ideas which EFI to use? Thank you.

EDIT: After installing OpenSUSE, the installer has created an entry (the entry was something like openuses-xxxxx) for me automatically. But this disappeared after removing the USB. Putting it back didn't recreate it.

parent folder

[image]

contents of boot folder

[image]

contents of opensuse folder

[image]

Comment: Do not know OpenSUSE, but all external devices boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi just like you boot the live installer.  Do you have an ESP - efi system partition (FAT32) on external drive with that file & folder?